# Highcharts distance from crosshair to tooltip

Tags: javascript, typescript, highcharts

In a Highcharts linear chart I have a formatted tooltip and crosshair enabled. The distance between tooltip and crosshair is rather big so a gap (marked in red) arises:

[image]

Setting

```
tooltip: {
    distance: 1
}
```

solves the problem visually, but then I get a compiler error:
 *Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'distance' does not exist in type 'TooltipOptions'*

Is there another way to minimize the gap between tooltip and crosshair?

These are my chart options concerning tooltip:

```
tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '',
    useHTML: true,
    backgroundColor: null,
    borderWidth: 0,
    shadow: false,
    shape: 'square',
    pointFormatter: function() {
      return '<div style="background-color:'+this.series.color+';color:white;padding:5px;font-size:12px;z-index:10">' + this.y.toLocaleString() + ' %</div>'
    },
    split: true,
    crosshairs: {
      color: '#333333',
      dashStyle: 'solid',
      width: 2,
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This space is caused by defualt value of `padding` property, you can reduce it in this way:

```
tooltip: {
    ...,
    padding: -8
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/2098/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/tooltip.padding